# Records get deleted automatically after inserting in table- hibernate/db2

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, db2

I am trying to insert 3 millions record to jvald_address table from ADDRESS table.
Records are inserted to jvald_address  table from ADDRESS table, but the records are deleted automatically from jvald_address  table after inserting 3 million records. Looks like problem with the QUERY interface in hibernate. Following is the code snippet.

```
public String getaddress()
    {
        // StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        /*for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {*/

        /*String del = "delete from jvald_address";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(del);
        query.executeUpdate();*/
        System.out.println("BEFORE queryaddress FETCH");
        String hql = "insert into jvald_address(JVALD_ADDRESS_KEY,JVALD_BUILDING_NUMBER,JVALD_CONCAT_INDICATOR,JVALD_DELIVERY_POINT_SUFF,JVALD_DEPENDENT_THR_DESC_KEY,JVALD_DEPENDENT_THR_KEY,JVALD_NUM_HOUSEHOLD,JVALD_PO_BOX_NUM,JVALD_POSTCODE_INWARD_OUTWARD_ID,JVALD_SMALL_USER_ORG_INDICATOR,JVALD_ORGANISATION_KEY_ID,JVALD_POSTCODE_TYPE,JVALD_SUB_BUILDING_NAME_KEY_ID,JVALD_BUILDING_NAME_KEY_ID,JVALD_THOROUGHFARE_DESC_KEY_ID,JVALD_THOROUGHFARE_KEY_ID,JVALD_LOCALITY_KEY_ID) select ADDRESS_KEY,BUILDING_NUMBER,CONCATENATION_INDICATOR,DELIVERY_POINT_SUFFIX,DEPENDENT_THOROUGHFARE_DESCRIPTOR_KEY,DEPENDENT_THOROUGHFARE_KEY,NUMBER_OF_HOUSEHOLDS,PO_BOXNUMBER,POSTCODE_OUTWARD_INWARD,SMALL_USER_ORGANISATION_INDICATOR,ORGANISATION_KEY,POSTCODE_TYPE,SUB_BUILDING_NAME_KEY,BUILDING_NAME_KEY,THOROUGHFARE_DESCRIPTOR_KEY,THOROUGHFARE_KEY,LOCALITY_KEY from ADDRESS";

        Query queryaddress = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
        queryaddress.setFetchSize(100000);
        queryaddress.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("AFTER queryaddress FETCH");

    /*    if( i % 50 == 0 ) // Same as the JDBC batch size
            { 
                //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }*/

        //session.close();

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Has there been an exception?  i.e. was there an automatic rollback performed by Db2.  Check in the database diagnostics file for evidence.

Comment: Was your DB configured to AUTO-COMMIT upon session termination?

Comment: how to check in db2 whether auto commit is enabled or not?

Comment: The SQL is inserting more than 3 million records using single SQL statement. DB2 might be throwing exception due to transaction log full condition and performing automatic rollback. Change database log file sizes to meet your requirement.

Comment: other tables are commited properly which has limited records like 50000